# Black desktop after login and problems with GUI in Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10 (currently using 13.10)

Tags: 12.10, 13.10, graphics, gui

I am having problems with the GUI when I log in. Please check out the youtube-link at the bottom first to see the problem. (I am currently using 13.10)

Problem: First of all, when I have logged in and reached the desktop it is black instead of showing the real background. The graphics lag when I move the pointer over icons (e.g the text that shows up describing the icons to the left remains after I have removed the pointer) and if I open a window and move it around trace of its graphics remains (like to paint the "frame" all over the background if I move it all over the desktop, common lag problem in Windows XP etc.).

What I do to fix the problem is simply to use xkill on the background and all the lag stops. The real desktop image comes back after a few minutes and everything turns to normal. I have done like this a couple of months but a better solution to the problem likely exists. I've had the same problem in 12.10 and 13.04, every time I have upgraded to a new version the problem have remained the same.

What should I do?

Link to a youtube-video showing my problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwFQfm7PaYM

Comment: I would go for a ubuntu-desktop reinstall. Try: sudo apt-get install --reinstall -y ubuntu-desktop 
Let's see what happens. 
Otherwise it would also be interesting to see what are the process running. Run an "htop" command to see if there is anything that is eating your resources. Also you should check if by entering "unity --replace" the problem goes away, if not, then... have you upgraded your drivers?, what about installing apps to manage wallpapers, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be a problem with your graphic card. Have you installed/updated your CG driver recently?

- If **yes**, can you try to go back with your former driver (you can choose your driver version in System parameters > Additional drivers)
- If **no**, try to install the newest driver for your card (again through System parameters > Additional drivers)